# Can I trust X-TRAP?

Tags: rusty-hearts

I have recently installed [Rusty Hearts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusty_Hearts) with the intention of trying it out, even though I'm not really an MMO person. Something in the game's aesthetic just really appeals to me.

While the gameplay videos I've seen looked decent, the installation experience itself had me questioning the game's credibility. The installer and subsequent launcher look slightly shady, with several suspicious windows popping up and disappearing.

When I finally got to launching the actual game, I suddenly saw the following icon before the game went full-screen:

[image: It's a trap!]

Snooping around online, I discovered that this is some sort of cheat-prevention module called X-Trap, that is aimed to detect the following, amongst other things:

> 1. The user has modified game files
> 2. The user is running a 3rd party program that is not allowed
> 3. The user is modifying the program dynamically

While I understand why cheat prevention is important in such games, my instincts are to be highly suspicious of this module. This is exacerbated by the fact that I can't seem to find any official information about it.

So my question is, can I trust X-Trap not to:

1. Spy on me.
2. Alter my computer in ways I am unaware of.
3. Interfere with other programs.
4. Do other bad things I can't necessarily think about.

Comment: **IT'S A TRAP!** (sorry, had to)

Comment: @Shaderach I was really holding myself back from writing the exact same thing somewhere.

Comment: I'd have gone with it in the question title, but the Fun Police would probably have stepped in and nuked it. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NOTE: I have not actually tried running X-Trap on my system - I looked it up while downloading the game, and canceled the download when I learned of this.

I found this [thread](http://rustyhearts-forum.perfectworld.com/showthread.php?t=75341) at the official forums, and apparently, programs like these can intefere with your ability to play the game:

> 1. Anti-virus programs that use SONAR or active background scanning
> 2. Internet security packages
> 3. Software for keyboards and mice LOGITECH im sorry guys but your
>      G15s and macro keyboards will cause you PAIN
> 4. Multimedia software Itunes, WMP, Xfire, Steam overlay, Podcast,
>      fraps
> 5. Torrent programs Utorrent bittorrent. etc.

Additionally, X-Trap requires administrative privileges, even to just run, which is a big no-no by today's standards.

I don't think X-Trap is malicious, and I understand why the developers feel the need for a system like this, but I consider it *far* too aggressive and invasive, more so because I *have* one of those Logitech keyboards. That's a shame, because I too want to try the game - but IMO, no game is worth dealing with that kind of problems.

Comment: It's strange that the Steam overlay is mentioned, since I got this through Steam. I saw such a list on a different thread and that was another reason for me to assume X-Trap is indeed aggressive. I just hope it doesn't leave any leftovers once I get rid of it.

Comment: @Aubergine: There is a small number of games on Steam which do not support the overlay - I can't remember any specific games right now, but I know Dungeons of Dredmor had issues with it on release. Also, I don't think the developers had a Steam launch in mind when choosing the system, and once Steam came into play, they were probably too far in development to consider changing the anti-cheating system to one that allows the overlay.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Same thing happened to me - I don't know whether it was the G15 software or iTunes that tripped XTrap and I decided I don't actually care; software that has a problem with what else I'm running is not welcome on my system.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think X-trap is *intentionally* malicious - but I don't trust it not to do damage out of incompetence or overzealousness instead.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen It's a horrible game anyway, nothing lost there.

Answer (score 3):

It actually is somewhat malicious in its over-zealousness. It silently and aggressively uninstalls certain programs that it red flags, apparently, which is a big no-no for me. Interestingly, it uninstalled a program I use frequently for work -.-

Comment: Could you please list which programs it uninstalled for you?

Comment: Woah, it actually *removes* programs from your computer without permission? That's got to be some sort of legal issue...

Answer (score 0):

You guys are just jumping the gun; I never have any issues like these on S4 League and it has X-Trap. The only thing is a non-steam version of S4 League with X-Trap- it won't start that game through Steam as a non-Steam game, but runs fine without Steam.

X-Trap does not uninstall programs, you must have let a virus in your computer or have a bad anti-virus. If I was you I would use ESET Smart Security 5 instead of other anti-viruses and do a full scan.

X-Trap is supposed to stop hackers, cheaters or anything that gives players an advantage over others- nothing more- unless you enjoy hackers in games. It's how you to deal with and report them if you don't want them in the game and only to play fair.